# Cannot import com.google. .... why?

Tags: android, api, import

I am simply trying to compile and run the example project from: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

I get the following errors:

package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist
package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist
package android.support.v4.app does not exist

I have tried the following already:

I have download Google API already, see screenshot of my SDK Manager window.

I saw different related posts but have not been successful in compiling this yet - even tried restarting computer.

Screenshot of my SDK Window showing Google API Installed: http://postimg.org/image/xf64h3fu3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Android Support library to your project.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

"In order to use a Support Library, you must modify your application's project's classpath dependencies within your development environment."

Comment: I already have it installed, see screenshot of my SDK Manager here: http://postimg.org/image/xf64h3fu3/

(posted link since i dont have votes yet in this forum to post images)

Comment: Just installing it in the SDK is not enough. You need to add it to every project you want to use it in. It's not clear that you have done that. Read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below Steps to need to follow after downloading it:

1. Right Click on your Project Explorer.
2. Select New-> Project -> Android Application Project from Existing Code
3. Browse upto this path only - "C:\Users**your path**\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"
4. This will add google play service project into eclipse
5. Now, Right click on your project (not google play service project) and select "Java Build path".
6. Select Libraries Tab and click on "Add Jars" button. Locate google_play_service project(NOTE: google play service project should not be closed in pkg explorer window) and add libraries from lib folder and click ok.
7. (**if still not appearing libs then follow this steps**) Again right click on your project, select properties and select "Android" option.
8. From left panel, select "Android" option.
9. Under "Library" section, you will see "Add" button. Click on that button and locate "google-play-services_lib".
10. Then click on Apply. It will be added to your project. :)